# How to hide a picture in an Excel cell?

Tags: excel

My excel sheet has many rows. Each row is a project. I want to put a picture into a cell and I hope the picture will be very small when I am NOT click on it. In other words, I don't want to see the full size picture until I click on the cell? How I could do that? Thanks

Comment: Use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to resize the picture, (or move it into view if you place it off-screen)

Comment: I am using Excel. Does Worksheet_SelectionChange need VBA?

Comment: Yes - I don't think you can do this without VBA

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to insert a picture into a cell's comment.  The picture will not appear unless you hover over the commented cell.  See this [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776611/insert-picture-into-excel-cell).

Comment: I read the previous SO answer, but my excel is a starter version which does not have "Colors and Lines " under "Format Comment"