# How to hide pictures in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have read an answer from [Insert picture into excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776611/insert-picture-into-excel-cell)

However, my Excel is a starter version which does not have "Colors and Lines " under "Format Comment"

I want to put my pictures into column H. Whenever I click on the cell, then the picture will enlarge. Possible?

Note: I have NO vba experience

Answer (score 1):

You add a picture (Name Picture 1) where you want. Add the follow code to the Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Prev Then
        Dim x
        x = ActiveCell.Address
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        Prev = False
        Range(x).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

and in a module (inside VBA Alt+F11 -> rightclick on : Sheet1 -> Insert -> module):

```
Public Prev As Boolean

Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Prev = True
End Sub
```

Assign to the picture the macro Macro1...(right mouse click on the picture -> Assign Macro)
When you click on the picture the picture enlarge, when you click on another cell, the picture reduce.

Answer (score 1):

Put picture to column H by selecting row number from combobox list, and fit picture to cell with align to center point, saving aspectratio

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    PTstop = Me.ComboBox1.value
    PicPath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Application.GetOpenFilename("*.jpg,*.png,*.jpeg,*.gif")
                    If PicPath <> False Then
                        With .Pictures.Insert(Filename:=PicPath)
                            With .ShapeRange
                                If .Width > .Height Then
                                    If .Height >= Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(PTstop, 8).Height Then
                                        .Height = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(PTstop, 8).Height
                                        If .Width >= Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(PTstop, 8).Width Then
                                            .Width = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(PTstop, 8).Width 
                                        Else
                                        End If
                                    Else
                                        .Width = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(PTstop, 8).Width
                                        If .Height >= Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(PTstop, 8).Height Then
                                            .Height = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(PTstop, 8).Height
                                        Else
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    .Height = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(PTstop , 8).Height
                                End If
                                .Top = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(PTstop, 8).Top + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(PTstop , 8).Height / 2 - .Height / 2
                                .Left = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(PTstop, 8).Left + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(PTstop, 8).Width / 2 - .Width / 2

                            End With
                        End With
                    End If
End Sub
```

Code to enlarge image then clicked to Right of Image, if click anywhere in column A, image should reduce in size. Not tested just as  starting point.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rangeS As Range, picSelected As Shape, old
If Target.Column > 1 Then
    Set rangeS = Target.Offset(, -1)
        For Each picSelected In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If TypeName(picSelected.OLEFormat.Object) = "Picture" Then
                If picSelected.TopLeftCell.Address = rangeS.Address Then
                    picSelected.Height = 250
                    picSelected.Width = 250
                End If
            End If
        Next picSelected
ElseIf Target.Column = 1 Then
    For Each picSelected In ActiveSheet.Shapes
       If TypeName(picSelected.OLEFormat.Object) = "Picture" Then
           With picSelected
                            If .Width > .Height Then
                                If .Height >= Target.Height Then
                                    .Height = Target.Height
                                Else
                                    .Width = Target.Width
                                    If .Height >= Target.Height Then
                                        .Height = Target.Height
                                    Else
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Else
                                .Height = Target.Height
                            End If
                            .Top = Target.Top + Target.Height / 2 - .Height / 2
                            .Left = Target.Left + Target.Width / 2 - .Width / 2

End With
       End If
   Next picSelected
End If
End Sub
```